# Pass array from controller to view - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, undefined, pass-data

I tried to print the array in the controller, before passing it to a view and this is the output

```
Array ( [annunci] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [EmailDatore] => you@welcom.it [Nome] => asdasd [Cognome] => asdas [IdAnnuncio] => 9 [Titolo] => sfsdfdsfshrea [Testo] => agrefdgdagdfg [Categoria] => [Sede] => [TipoContratto] => [Add_Date] => [Drop_Date] => ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( [EmailDatore] => you@welcom.it [Nome] => asdasd [Cognome] => asdas [IdAnnuncio] => 10 [Titolo] => fafa [Testo] => fafaerea asdasdas dafasfd [Categoria] => [Sede] => [TipoContratto] => [Add_Date] => [Drop_Date] => ) ) )
```

I get the array from this method in my maincontroller

```
 public function get_annunci(){


    $query=$this->user_model->annunci($this->email);        
    print_r($query);        
    }
```

I would like to pass this array to a view and then read the data. So i rewrite my method like this

```
public function get_annunci(){
    $query=$this->user_model->annunci($this->email);        
    $this->load->view('main_view',$query);      
}
```

In main view i have this

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="annunci">
    <ul>
        <?php
        print_r($annunci);
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is my error

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: annunci

Filename: views/tab_annunci_view.php

Line Number: 4
```

Comment: Your error shows that you are trying to load `views/tab_annunci_view.php` but your code says `main_view`.

Comment: Every single view in my application loads with this line: $this->load->view('templates/template',$data); What he's calling in the controller has nothing to do with the actual view file name at that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function get_annunci(){
    $query['annunci']=$this->user_model->annunci($this->email);        
    $this->load->view('main_view',$query);      
}
```

You're passing the array but you aren't passing annunci as a variable.

Answer (score 5):

This is because you have not defined $annunci and made it available to the view. You need to load it to the view first by

**Controller**

```
$data['id'] = $yourArray;
$this->load->view('your_view_file', $data);
```

**View**

```
 <?php print_r($id); ?> //prints $yourArray
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public function index()
    {
        $data=$this->model->viewBlog();
        $this->load->view('blog/index',['data'=>$data]);
    }
```

I hope this is work.
if you handle n number of records use this method.

Answer (score 2):

(Change `$query` to `$query ['annunci']`)
OK, the `$query` is an array already, then just change the view file to 'tab_annunci_view'

So:

```
public function get_annunci(){
    $query=$this->user_model->annunci($this->email);        
    $this->load->view('tab_annunci_view',$query);      
}
```

Comment: Print out in the first line shows that he has already created index `annunci`.

Comment: I edited the answer you just have to change the view file to 'tab_annunci_view'.

Comment: Why would you make that edit? He's quite obviously calling the right view since he's getting the undefined variable error. Otherwise he'd get a 404.

Comment: @Rick Clader he said 'Print out in the first line shows that he has already created index' what means $query is an array

Comment: Look at the error he's receiving, line 4 is where he tries to output annunci, therefore he has to be loading the right view. See my comment on his original post, what it says in that line does not have to match the actual view file name.