# How To Do Foreach in CodeIgniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, foreach

how to do foreach in codeigniter controller
I want to run a select query in the codeigniter 3 controller with foreach and do the calculations for the data, then it will insert into the table

Comment: Related: [Pass array from controller to view - Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13387729/2943403) and [codeigniter passing array data from model to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14121978/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your select method in your model

```
public function get_all_rows()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('table_name');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

and then you can call and iterate it in your controller like this:

```
$this->load->model('my_model');
$data = $this->my_model->get_all_rows();

foreach($data as $item)
{
    echo $item['name'];
}
```

Also you can see this link for more information:
https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/news_section.html

Comment: Of course a controller should be passing data to a view for displaying purposes.  In the model, `$query` never needs to be defined; it will be simpler to just chain the `result_array()` call to the `get()` call.

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, you have to understand the concept of MVC in Codeigniter firstly

you can learn it in this link for complete information https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/overview/mvc.html

For your case maybe you can write like code below, of course must be adjusted to your needs

```
$data = array();

# call model method
$dataA = $this->YourModelClassName->getAllDataFromTable_A();

# check if not empty
if (!empty($dataA)) {
    

    # do looping
    foreach ($dataA as $key => $val) {

        # just example, maybe you want encode the Id field
        $dataA[$key]['id'] = $this->encrypt->encode($val['id']);

        # do some calculation as you want here, this is just example
        $dataA[$key]['calculation'] = ($val['field_A'] + $val['field_B']) * $val['field_C'];
    }
    
    $data['data_A'] = $dataA;
}


# send to view if you want
$this->load->view('your_view_name', $data);

# but if you wanna save it to table you just add some insert or update data instruction
```

Hopefully it can help you

Comment: In my humble opinion, there is no need for `!empty()` because the data returned from the model method is expected to be an empty or populated array.  This means that it can be passed unconditionally to the `foreach()` loop.